# Getting all Versions of one Record in Apache Pig with HBaseStorage()

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

im using the org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage() in Pig Latin. Is it possible to get ALL Versions of one Value?

In the HBase Shell the command is:

```
get 'table', 'cf:column', {COLUMN => 'cf:column', VERSIONS => 5}
```

Is it possible in Pig too?

Input Sample:

My HBase Table looks like this:

```
hbase(main):019:0> put 'mytable', 'mykey1', 'cf:onlyoneclumn', 'value 1'
0 row(s) in 0.0070 seconds

hbase(main):020:0> put 'mytable', 'mykey1', 'cf:onlyoneclumn', 'value 2'
0 row(s) in 0.0070 seconds

hbase(main):021:0> put 'mytable', 'mykey1', 'cf:onlyoneclumn', 'value 3'
0 row(s) in 0.0050 seconds

hbase(main):022:0> put 'mytable', 'mykey1', 'cf:onlyoneclumn', 'value 4'
0 row(s) in 0.0050 seconds

hbase(main):023:0> get 'mytable', 'mykey1'
COLUMN                CELL                                                      
 cf:onlyoneclumn      timestamp=1376470137654, value=value 4                    
1 row(s) in 0.0370 seconds

hbase(main):024:0> get 'mytable', 'mykey1',  {COLUMN => 'cf:onlyoneclumn', VERSIONS => 5}
COLUMN                CELL                                                      
 cf:onlyoneclumn      timestamp=1376470137654, value=value 4                    
 cf:onlyoneclumn      timestamp=1376470136632, value=value 3                    
 cf:onlyoneclumn      timestamp=1376470135411, value=value 2                    
3 row(s) in 0.0140 seconds
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and example output?

Comment: OKay - I've added an example from the hbase shell

Answer (score 1):

The current(0.11.1)  HBaseStorage which is the class pig ships with to read HBase tables does not support it. It only supports the following

> ```
> optString - Loader options. Known options:
> -loadKey=(true|false) Load the row key as the first column
> -gt=minKeyVal
> -lt=maxKeyVal
> -gte=minKeyVal
> -lte=maxKeyVal
> -limit=numRowsPerRegion max number of rows to retrieve per region
> -delim=char delimiter to use when parsing column names (default is space or comma)
> -ignoreWhitespace=(true|false) ignore spaces when parsing column names (default true)
> -caching=numRows number of rows to cache (faster scans, more memory).
> -noWAL=(true|false) Sets the write ahead to false for faster loading.
> -minTimestamp= Scan's timestamp for min timeRange
> -maxTimestamp= Scan's timestamp for max timeRange
> -timestamp= Scan's specified timestamp
> -caster=(HBaseBinaryConverter|Utf8StorageConverter) Utf8StorageConverter is the default To be used with extreme caution,
> ```
>
> since this could result in data loss (see
>   http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#perf.hbase.client.putwal).

What you can do is get the [HBaseStorage code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.java), and build your own Loader that does support it

Comment: Arnon, something has changed since then? We also need this feature.

Comment: Hi Hersh :) - you can look at the code at the link (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.java)  it is pretty similar with a couple of additional options. You can however build your own "HBaseStorage" based on this code to fill the gap